# New trigger in sql server 2005 database

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, triggers

The database I am using already has a 2 triggers on part number table (on insert and on update). Insert trigger updates creation date, and update trigger updates modification date.

I have to add 3 more triggers to log updates to this table (on insert, on update and on delete)

In what order they will be executed? Before existing trigger or after? Can I control that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sp_settriggerorder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx) will allow you to set first or last trigger.

If you have more than two and the order matters, combine them into one trigger and split the functionality over the stored procedures.